# How to solve apache shutdown issue in production without restart manually

Tags: apache

My website shutdown twice a day. But when i restart the apache it works fine. In apache error.log file i find AH00491 caught sigterm, shutting down ubuntu.

Comment: Is there anything else in your logs before the AH00491?  This can indicate the server ran out of threads (MaxClients reached the max), or some other resource exhaustion.

Comment: Before that i got another error log message "AH00094 command line '/usr/sbin/apache2'"

Comment: That is ok, it is just saying which exec file it is using.  So other suggestion, turn on /server-status and look at your workers.  Look if all are used before it crashes.  Turn your logs to debug mode (watch for disk space exhaustion!) and hopefully you will get more info.